# How to insert multiple different textboxes to database table one by one for each row?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I have 3 different textboxes for serials. And when I click the button I want to save them for each row in database table.

```
Textbox1.Text="HP" ==> STOCKID   
Textbox2.Text="İ5" ==> MODEL   
Textbox3.Text="3" ==> QUANTITY   
Textbox4.Text="11231231"; ==> SERIAL-1   
Textbox5.Text="11231231"; ==> SERIAL-2   
Textbox6.Text="11231231"; ==> SERIAL-2
```

Then Button click event.

Result should be as below.

FIRST GRIDVIEW

| STOKID | MODEL | QUANTİTY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| HP | I5 | 3 |

SECOND GRIDVIEW

| STOKID | MODEL | SERIALS | DELETEBUTTON |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HP | I5 | 32165161 | BUTTON |
| HP | I5 | 12313223 | BUTTON |
| HP | I5 | 16516516 | BUTTON |

When I delete from serials one bye one, the first Gridview QTY should decrease one for each serials. Is it possible?

I use a stored procedure during insert to data for first gridview. But for second one I don't know how to use a loop for textboxes and add to database different serials (textboxes values).

Comment: I've switched your post to use markdown, rather than HTML. Please do take the time to have a read of [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), as formatting your posts well is a great way to help them be well received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so say this markup:

We have Stokkid, model, and then have 3 optional serial num boxes
(if they are left blank - we don't add).

So, this markup:

The boxes, and add button:

```
        <div style="float: left">
            <h4>Stokid</h4>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtStokID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left;margin-left:20px">
            <h4>Model</h4>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtModel" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left;margin-left:20px">
            <h4>Serial 1</h4>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtS1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left;margin-left:20px">
            <h4>Serial 2</h4>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtS2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left;margin-left:20px">
            <h4>Serial 3</h4>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtS3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left;margin-left:20px;margin-top:20px">
            <asp:Button ID="cmdSave" runat="server" Text="Save/Add" CssClass="btn" 
                OnClick="cmdSave_Click"
                />
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both" ></div>
```

And right below that, 2 grids, the first totals gv, and then the data we have gv.

So, this:

```
        <h3>Counts</h3>
        <asp:GridView ID="GVCounts" runat="server" CssClass="table"
            width="40%" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" >
        </asp:GridView>

        <h3>Items</h3>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table"
            width="40%" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" >
        </asp:GridView>
```

And now our code to load up the above:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadData();
    }

    void LoadData()
    {

        // load up "counts" grid
        string strSQL =
             @"SELECT Stokid, Model, count(*) as QTY FROM tblSerials 
               GROUP BY Stokid, Model";

        GVCounts.DataSource = MyRst(strSQL);
        GVCounts.DataBind();

        // Load up existing data grid

        strSQL =
             @"SELECT Stokid, Model, Serials FROM tblSerials ORDER BY ID";

        GridView1.DataSource = MyRst(strSQL);
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
```

So, only part left is the "add new data button"

That code is this:

```
    protected void cmdSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // save (add) one row for each serial number, 
        // if no serial - then don't add

        DataTable dt = MyRst("SELECT * FROM tblSerials WHERE ID = 0");
        DataRow MyAddRow = dt.NewRow();
        MyAddRow["Stokid"] = txtStokID.Text;
        MyAddRow["Model"] = txtModel.Text;
        MyAddRow["Serials"] = txtS1.Text;

        dt.Rows.Add(MyAddRow);

        if (txtS2.Text != "")
        {
            MyAddRow = dt.NewRow();
            MyAddRow["Stokid"] = txtStokID.Text;
            MyAddRow["Model"] = txtModel.Text;
            MyAddRow["Serials"] = txtS2.Text;
            dt.Rows.Add(MyAddRow);
        }
        if (txtS3.Text != "")
        {
            MyAddRow = dt.NewRow();
            MyAddRow["Stokid"] = txtStokID.Text;
            MyAddRow["Model"] = txtModel.Text;
            MyAddRow["Serials"] = txtS3.Text;
            dt.Rows.Add(MyAddRow);
        }

        // send/save all rows to database
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST5))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblSerials", conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL);
                SqlCommandBuilder daU = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
                da.Update(dt);
            }
        }

        // Update counts and display
        LoadData();
    }
```

so, the result is now this:

[image]

Now, we do probably want to setup a delete button.

so, that means our "cheat" life and easy GV of data?

Well, we have to give it a bit more effort, love and care.

We need the database PK id, and we want that delete button.

And since the delete button can be a danger, then it should confirm.

So, we have to update our GV a bit, bite the bullet and use some templating. but, it is not much.

And lets use a boot-strap icon - they should be part of any most recent project by defualt. But BE warned, after boottrap 4, the later versions (due to some copyright/lawsuit, bootstrap does not include the glyph-icons).

Anyway, I COULD use a plain jane asp.net button in the gv for delete, but lets use standard html button - I ONLY use the html one, since I wanted the cute icon. Probably better for you to use a image button.
(code is much  the same either way).

So, our 2nd gv now looks like this:

```
<h3>Items</h3>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table table-hover"
    width="40%" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" DataKeyNames="ID" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"  >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="STOKID" HeaderText="STOKID"    />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MODEL" HeaderText="MODEL"      />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="serials" HeaderText="serials"  />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" ItemStyle-Width="80px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <button id="cmdDelete" runat="server" class="btn"
                    onclick="if (!confirm('Delete')) return false;"
                    onserverclick="cmdDel_ServerClick" >
                    <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                </button>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And the code to load up this gv is now:

```
    void LoadData()
    {

        // load up "counts" grid
        string strSQL =
             @"SELECT Stokid, Model, count(*) as QTY FROM tblSerials 
               GROUP BY Stokid, Model";

        GVCounts.DataSource = MyRst(strSQL);
        GVCounts.DataBind();

        // Load up existing data grid

        strSQL = @"SELECT * FROM tblSerials ORDER BY ID";

        GridView1.DataSource = MyRst(strSQL);
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
```

And our delete code is this:

```
    protected void cmdDel_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        HtmlButton btn = (HtmlButton)sender;
        GridViewRow gRow = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;

        int PKID = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[gRow.RowIndex]["ID"];
        string strSQL = "DELETE FROM tblSerial WHERE ID = {PKID}";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST5))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        // update count and items gv
        LoadData();
    }
```

So, now we see, get this for a delete:

[image]

## Edit2: The Myrst routine

In a few places in above, I also used this helper routine, since I get VERY tired VERY fast having to write code each and every time I want some data, so, I wrote and use this routine:

```
    DataTable MyRst(string strSQL)
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST5))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }
```

It handy for filling out a gridview, dropdown list etc.

Comment: Mr.Albert, thank you so so much. I am really happy bec. Somebody helped me. I wish you my best wishes:)

Comment: Great, there is lots of good ideas in this post. If you found this as help, then do mark this as an answer out of curtsey.

Comment: I did not want to have to write out a sql insert statement(s), so I pull a non existing row into the data table to get all the columns and table structure. Then I proceed to add a row for each text box that has a entry, and thus since the first two columns are the same, but ONLY the 3 serial numbers, then the code that follows was able to use  dt.NewRow(); (create a new row based on that existing table I pulled).  I mean, we could have used/written a sql insert statement, but I often find that using data table, and data row is less effort then writing SQL insert statements and parameter's.

Comment: This also allowed me to add 3 rows, and THEN send any and all updates (rows added) to the database in one shot. So, often I will use a data table + data row, as it is less messy then SQL, and as the example shows, I am able to add 1, 2 or 3 rows (or maybe even more). once done, I can then send ALL of those new rows to the database in one shot with the da.Update(dt);

Comment: Also, see my edit#2, I had left out the MyRst routine (all it does is return a data table based on the SQL passed).